# Cakephp FindById with run just with a number

Tags: cakephp

I try to do a ticket system for administration . So I have a User model is as follows :

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel {
  public $name = 'User';
    public $hasMany = 'Ticket';
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Un nom d\'utilisateur est requis.'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Un mot de passe est requis.'
            )
        ),
        'role' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('administrateur', 'developpeur', 'technicien', 'commercial')),
                'message' => 'Merci de rentrer un rôle valide',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When the user logs in with a username and password, it comes to the administration area where should the tickets **list by users**.

Here is my model my ticket :

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Ticket extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'List';
    public $tablePrefix = 'tickets_';
    public $belongsTo = array(
                            'User' => array(
                            'foreignKey' => 'username_id'
                        )
   );

}
```

And here's the code for my controller Ticket :

```
class TicketsController extends TicketAppController{

    public function index(){
        $this->request->data['Ticket']['username_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->set('list', $this->Ticket->findById($this->data['Ticket']['username_id']));
    }

}
```

When I put findById (5 ), for example I have the right ticket that appears with the connected user associated. But put instead of 5 for whatever the user via its id ticket is displayed ?

Comment: Have you tried with my posted answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think this:

```
class TicketsController extends TicketAppController{

    public function index(){
        $this->request->data['Ticket']['username_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->set('list', $this->Ticket->findById($this->data['Ticket']['username_id']));
    }

}
```

Should be this:

```
class TicketsController extends TicketAppController{

    public function index(){
        $this->request->data['Ticket']['username_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->set('list', $this->Ticket->findByUsernameId($this->data['Ticket']['username_id']));
    }

}
```

Mark the `findByUsernameId`. You are searching on the username_id, not the id of the ticket.
Got it? ;)

Comment: And, I should rename your field to `user_id`, not `username_id` ;)

Comment: Same problem in these 2 cases : when i try to var_dump $list it return array(0){}

Comment: @user3601175: use the `debug()`-function do debug your data. `$this->data["Ticket"]` should be `$this->request->data["Ticket"]`. See the diffrence between the first and second rule in the `index()`-method

Comment: it's good. it works with $this->request->data["Ticket"]. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

> You can not change `$this->request->data` so try to take variable **$user_id** 
>      instead of **$this->request->data['Ticket']['username_id']**

```
class TicketsController extends TicketAppController{

    public function index(){
        $user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->set('list', $this->Ticket->findById($user_id));
    }

}
```